Can system variables reference user variables?
What it says on the tin.
I want a system variable %dl% = %USERPROFILE%\Downloads
for Jon: %dl% = C:\Users\Jon\Downloads
for Ann: %dl% = C:\Users\Ann\Downloads
and so forth.
Will that work, or do I have to create a separate DL user variable for each user?

Try echo %userprofile%\downloads in CMD -- is that what you want??

What's your goal? If the sys var depends on the user var it can only be used in user context, where the user var is already defined. The sys var seems pointless.

You can't have variables in the value of other variables. (You might be able to set it, but it doesn't expand the variable at runtime)
You can create a user variable %dl% under each user profile?
You could also have a logon script set it for you each time?
Using %userprofile%\Downloads and not creating an alias to it is probably a safer idea?
